# How do compile a simple program using boost::thread in cygwin?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, cygwin

I installed the boost package from cygwin and have a directory /usr/include/boost that includes a bunch of *.hpp files, including thread.hpp, which I need to include in the c++ file, via

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

Also, several *.a files seem to be related to boost::thread.

```
$ ls /usr/lib/libboost_thread* -1
/usr/lib/libboost_thread-gcc-mt-1_33_1.a
/usr/lib/libboost_thread-gcc-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.a
/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dll.a
```

What should my g++ compilation command look like? I understand I should be using some combination of -L -I, and -l, but I'm not sure what to supply for each argument, and nothing is working for me so far.

I have tried the following:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -lboost_thread-gcc-mt
/cygdrive/c/Users/jonderry/AppData/Local/Temp/ccaNCMaA.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEED
0Ev[boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>::~thread_data()]+0x16): undefined reference to `boost::detail::thre
ad_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
...
...
```

Comment: Didn't installing the package install also the prebuilt libraries?

Comment: Maybe, but I can't find them. The directory /usr/include/boost just contains a bunch of hpp files.

Comment: /usr/include is for headers. Libs are elsewhere, maybe in one of /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib or /usr/share/lib - I don't know exactly where for cygwin. If none of these contain them, `find /usr -name "libboost_*"` will help :)

Comment: OK, I added some details and refined the question. Thanks!

Comment: Boost 1.33.1? That's way too old! At that time Boost.Thread might well had some problems with cygwin support. Can you try a newer version?

Comment: Besides, there have been some backward-incompatible changes in Boost.Thread around 1.34 IIRC, so not using earlier versions is strongly advised to avoid upgrading difficulties later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT (removed -gcc part): `g++ sample.cpp -lboost_thread-mt`. You may need to add `-lpthread` or `-pthread` as well. If still no luck, please post the errors you get. HTH

Comment: Question updated with the error output. I tried -lpthread and -pthread as well, but the result was the same (-pthread was an unrecognized option)

Comment: @jonderry: Strange. Does `-lboost_thread-mt` (without -gcc) work better?

Comment: @jonderry: Glad it helped. Anyway here is the changes history for Boost.Thread: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/changes.html