# Create new thread in windows with cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, cygwin

I am using netbeans. I installed cygwin and use it for c++ programming in netbeans. I want to create a thread. I searched lots of sites. But I couldn't find anything suitable for my condition(C++ and windows(as OS) and not visual C++).

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926336/how-do-compile-a-simple-program-using-boostthread-in-cygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin implements the POSIX Threads API, aka [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads).

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options:

- [Win32 Process and Thread functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Boost Thread Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread.html)
- [POSIX Threads for Win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) ([POSIX Threads Programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/))

By the way, Visual C++ is just an IDE. It has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: If I may be pedantic: Visual C++ is a compiler, Visual Studio is the IDE, and in this case, Visual <whatever> implies the Win32 API, which is really *not* usable from a cygwin program.

Comment: @ Vlad Lazarenko. Coding in visual c++ is limited. I want to manage memory by myself. Is it possible in visual c++? I don't want GC. Is it possible in visual c++?

Comment: @rubenvb: "Microsoft Visual C++ (often abbreviated as MSVC or VC++) is a commercial, non-free integrated development environment (IDE) product from Microsoft..." by Wikipedia

Comment: @MHabibi: Visual C++ is an IDE. It is related to memory management in C++ as much as Notepad does.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko I bought a MSVC. I want to write a code in c++. But someone told me that memory management is done by GC in MSVC. Can I disable it? Can I manage memory by myself?

Comment: @Vlad: well then, wiki isn't as pedantic as me. It's strange you can *compile* F#/.net/VB/VB.net programs in a C++ IDE... And the compilers are free in the Windows SDK. You can use them perfectly without the IDE. And just for the fun of throwing back links: [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio). I got there reading the [the last sentence here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#Current_editions) on the page you linked. Wikipedia is great, but far from perfect... I stand by my point.

Comment: @rubenvb Actually the Windows API can be used from Cygwin programs, and some Cygwin programs such as the Xwin server or the mintty terminal do that quite extensively. You do have to be careful about it though, so for example you can create threads through the Windows API, but you shouldn't expect to be able to use POSIX APIs from within such threads.

Comment: @ak2: OK, didn't know that, but as you say, prudence is needed. I imagine that kind of trouble is not what the OP is after.